# push down child div out of parent div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a html markup like this

```
<div class="relative">
     <div id="absolute">
        <p>absolute content</p>
     </div>  
   <p>Parent div</p>
</div>
<div>outer content</div>
```

and css is

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ddd;
}
#absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

Now for some reason I want to take out the child div (id=absolute) out of its parent (id=relative) while pushing down whatever content in below the parent div.

This is what I want to get,
[image]

any help is appreciated

Comment: Use top for absolute div to push it down.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/8eXEE/

**HTML**

```
<div class="relative">
     <div id="absolute">
        <p>absolute content</p>
     </div>  
   <p>Parent div</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color:#ff0000; width:400px; height:100px; position: relative; top:200px;">outer content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ddd;
}
#absolute {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
    margin-bottom: -200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `#absolute` divs height does not dynamically changes (i.e. remains 200px always)

**The markup**

```
<div class="relative">
     <div id="absolute">
        <p>absolute content</p>
     </div>  
   <p>Parent div</p>
</div>
<div id="outer">outer content</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ddd;
}

#absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

#outer {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:200px;
  background:blue;
}
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jX18bpujbJcmmrryRHR4) , you can play with it.